# Why cv.matchShape is NOT invariant to translation as it claims?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, matching, similarity, pattern-recognition

I have two contours to match (think of them as any arbitrary 2D closed curves). `opencv` claims to have `matchShapes` function that is invariant under translation, rotation and scale. But it seems to me that this is not the case, when I add shift `(10, 5)` to one of the curves, the function returns a different result, let alone if I did something whackier. Why is that?

[matchShape](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html)

Reproducible example:

```
t = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.001)
x, y = np.cos(t), np.sin(t)
xy = np.stack([x, y], -1)
print(cv.matchShapes(xy, xy, 1, 0))
print(cv.matchShapes(xy, xy + (2, 10), 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects you send to `cv.matchShapes()` need to be `contour` objects which are different to a straight up 2D `numpy` array. The following code converts your curves to a plot,

[image]

then to an image & the contours of the 2 curves are found.

[image]

Finally `cv.matchShapes()` is run.

The output: `0` for the self match & `6.637412841570267e-12` for the match with the translated curve, a pretty accurate match under translation.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig  = plt.figure()
ax   = fig.add_subplot(111)
t    = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.001)
x, y = np.cos(t), np.sin(t)
ax.plot(x, y)

x_new = x + 2
y_new = y + 10
ax.plot(x_new, y_new, 'b')

[s.set_visible(False) for s in ax.spines.values()]
[t.set_visible(False) for t in ax.get_xticklines()]
[t.set_visible(False) for t in ax.get_yticklines()]
ax.axis('off')

plt.savefig('xy.jpg')

xy_img          = cv.imread('xy.jpg',  cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
xy_cpy          = cv.cvtColor(xy_img,   cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(threshold, bw) = cv.threshold(xy_cpy, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hier  = cv.findContours(bw, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours        = contours[0:-1] # remove box surounding whole image

print(cv.matchShapes(contours[0], contours[0], method=cv.CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, parameter=0))
print(cv.matchShapes(contours[0], contours[1], method=cv.CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, parameter=0))

cv.namedWindow("xy")
cv.drawContours(xy_img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv.imshow("xy", xy_img)

cv.waitKey()
```

Comment: Okay, but how exactly does a contour differ from a curve? Isn't just a closed curve? In this case `t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.001)` I complete the circle to 2 pi, but still not invariant.

Comment: `contours` are image space objects ie they contain the coordinates of the pixels that are contained in a contour which are `int` as you cant have a fraction of a pixel. Does that make sense? Have a look at `contours` in a variable viewer you'll see the difference.